# How to Add an annotation At your current location using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have everything working except the actual button function code. Here is My code but it does not add an annotation.

```
@IBAction func AddAnnotation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        CLLocationManager().startUpdatingLocation()
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        // Set the annotation by the lat and long variables
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        annotation.title = "My Car"
        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
```

Comment: Location updates will be reported to the location manager delegate method. You have to set your object as the delegate and wait for the call to `didUpdateLocation`

Comment: I am new to the coding world. so whatdo you mean by that?

Comment: It may take time for location services to determine your location (several seconds if the GPS isn't already running). So it calls back to the delegate method when the location is determined. You also need to request location permission from the user. I suggest you read the core location documentation or search for a tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't possibly work. When you call `startUpdatingLocation()`, it takes several seconds for the GPS to start up and get an accurate fix. you have to set yourself up as it's delegate, and then wait for your `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` method to be called.

You'd put your code to add an annotation in that method.

As others have said, you also need to write code that checks to see if you are authorized to get the user's location, and ask permission if not. (And You'll need to add a special key to your app's info.plist file indicating that your app needs access to the user's location.)

Take a look at the documentation on Core Location and using the location Manager in Xcode, and you might want to find a tutorial that walks you through the steps. It's a little involved.